# Reversing a name - Printing garbage after first name letter

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to write a program that reverses a name.

I'm using `gets()` to read the string, so it doesn't put the `\n` in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_name(char *name)
{
    const char *p = name;
    char initial;

    while (*p == ' ')       // skip preceding white-spaces
        p++;

    initial = *p++;         // store letter of first name

    while (*p != ' ')       // skip until first white-space
        p++;                // between first and last name

    while (*p == ' ')       // skip additional white-spaces
        p++;                // p now points to the first letter of the last name

    strcpy(name, p);        // copy last name to the beginning
    strcat(name, ", ");
    strcat(name, &initial);
    strcat(name, ".");
}
```

For example, when inputting `Immanuel Kant` it should output `Kant, I.`. It prints garbage between the `I` and the `.` though. What's going wrong?

Comment: `initial` is only a char and lack a null terminating `\0` character. So `strcat` copies until it encounters the terminating null character. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcat(name, &initial)` tries to treat the data at `&initial` as a C string, which is *NULL-terminated*. It will continue copying data from this address until it finds the null byte. But `&initial` is a pointer to a byte on the stack, and there's no guarantee that `*(&initial + 1) == 0`, so it continues copying whatever data it finds on the stack into the string.

As pointed out in the comments, `strcopy`ing a part of a string into another part of *the same string* is undefined behavior. [The `memmove` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) is safer in this regard. However, you should probably just allocate a new memory region and build the resulting string there instead.

Comment: This is one of the problems, copying a string on itself has undefined behavior too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can assume the initial is always 1 char, use this instead of the failing strcat.

```
strncat(name, &initial, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple major problems in your code:

- `while (*p != ' ') p++;` makes a bold assumption that the string contains at least one space after the first word. Calling `reverse_name` with the credentials of `"Superman"` or `"Madonna"`, or just an empty string will cause undefined behavior.
- `strcpy(name, p);` violates a constaint on the arguments of `strcpy`: copying between overlapping strings has undefined behavior.
- `strcat(name, &initial);` passes the address of a single `char`, which is not a valid C string. You can append a single `char` with `strncat(name, &initial, 1)`.

You just cannot simply perform the inversion in place as coded, and should be aware that the resulting string might be longer than the source string.

Here is an corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_name(char *name) {
    char *copy = strdup(name);

    char *first = copy + strspn(copy, " ");  // skip spaces before the first name
    int first_length = strcspn(first, " ");
    char *last = first + first_length + strspn(first + first_length);
    int last_length = strcspn(last, " ");

    if (last_length == 0) {
        /* no name or a single name */
        sprintf(name, "%.*s", first_length, first);
    } else {
        sprintf(name, "%.*s, %c.", last_length, last, *first);
    }
    free(copy);
}
```

Comment: Regarding your first point: I should have clarified that one is assumed to ener a first and last name, so input like ```"Superman"``` is ignored here. Thanks for pointing out though!

Comment: @Shuster: defensive programming is a good idea, avoiding undefined behavior in unexpected situations.